# How to make sure if all the radio buttons are checked by the user?

Tags: android, if-statement, radio-group

So I am trying to make a simple quiz application and I want to make sure that the user answers all the question before continuing to the next activity. At start the button I have set is unavailable and I want to make it available ONLY if all the question have been answered. I cant figure out where and how to check if all the question have an answer.

```
public class Quiz extends Activity 
{
Button buttHole;


String countryName[] = { "India", "Pakistan", "China", "Nepal", "Pichmaala",  "Blah" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    buttHole = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    buttHole.setEnabled(false);

    //Creating the list of Questions
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);

      for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)        
      {
       //create text button
       TextView title = new TextView(this);
       title.setText("Question Number:" + i);
       title.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
       mLinearLayout.addView(title);

       // create radio button
       final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[countryName.length];
       RadioGroup radGr = new RadioGroup(this);
       radGr.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
       radGr.setOnClickListener(l)

       for (int j = 0; j < countryName.length; j++) 
       {
        rb[j] = new RadioButton(this);
        radGr.addView(rb[j]);
        rb[j].setText(countryName[j]);       
       }
       mLinearLayout.addView(radGr);
       }



}
```

}

Comment: You have to get the selected radio button for each radio group using `getCheckedRadioButtonId()`. This will return -1 if a button is not selected.

Comment: I don't know, what you are doing. But I check my second solution. Which is running perfect as per your requirement. It will give you `false` if any of the question's answer is remaining. And this is your question `I cant figure out where and how to check if all the question have an answer`. And its working perfect in my answer. If method return `false` means more then one answers are remaining to answer. And `true` means, all answer are given.

Comment: Hmm ok this is becoming quite an interesting problem. Let me think.
Where should I call the checkQuestionsAnswer() method? I am colling it in the onCreate method outside the for loop is this correct?
If I dont call it it is never reached by the code. 
Also I see that u have onClickListener "l" where do you declare the "l" variable since I dont see its declaration in the solution you suggested. I have removed the radGr.setOnClickListener(l); since it is not declared anywhere and not used. 
I am terribly sorry but this problem is bugging me all day and its getting on my nerves

Comment: @user3182266 don't you find my answer helpful??

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to check whether user has given answer to all question or not

**First Solution**

```
int count = mLinearLayout.getChildCount();

for(int i=1;i<count ;i+=2){
    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1){
        //Answer is not selected
        //Do something to prevent execution
        break;
    }
}
```

**Second Solution**

```
public class Quiz extends Activity {
Button buttHole;

String countryName[] = { "India", "Pakistan", "China", "Nepal",
        "Pichmaala", "Blah" };

ArrayList<RadioGroup> arrGroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    buttHole = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    buttHole.setEnabled(false);

    // Creating the list of Questions
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
    arrGroup = new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        // create text button
        TextView title = new TextView(this);
        title.setText("Question Number:" + i);
        title.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        mLinearLayout.addView(title);

        // create radio button
        final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[countryName.length];
        RadioGroup radGr = new RadioGroup(this);
        // take a reference of RadioGroup view
        arrGroup.add(radGr);

        radGr.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        radGr.setOnClickListener(l);

        for (int j = 0; j < countryName.length; j++) {
            rb[j] = new RadioButton(this);
            radGr.addView(rb[j]);
            rb[j].setText(countryName[j]);
        }
        mLinearLayout.addView(radGr);
    }
}

public boolean checkQuestionsAnswer() {
    int count = arrGroup.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (arrGroup.get(i).getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
            //Return false, answer is remaining to given
            //You can pass here position also to know question number
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Return true if all answer are given
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: With your code the program crashes at 

RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i); //source not found

Comment: @user3182266 can you put full stack trace (logs) for this.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioGroup

Comment: @user3182266, oh i m sorry. I made a mistake. You have entered first `TextView` and then `RadioGroup`. Its my mistake. Let me solve this. Please be patient..:)

Comment: @user3182266, please check my edited answer. Use `checkQuestionsAnswer` method to get output of your question. :)

Comment: hmm your new code doesn't seem to work properly after

Comment: if (arrGroup.get(i).getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
            //Return false, answer is remaining to given
            //You can pass here position also to know question number
            return false;

it goes to return true and even If I have A toast in all the answers are given it is not called

Comment: @user3182266 first solution also??

Comment: the first one pops the error 

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioGroup

Comment: @user3182266 Does `mLinearLayout` have a child from XML that is still present when you add your title and then the `RadioGroup`? So that this child would be index "0", the title would be "1"/"3"/"5"/... and the `RadioGroup` would be "2"/"4"/"6"/... If not, try cleaning your project because from the code you provided the (first) solution of Chintan Rathod should work ;)

Comment: WHAT the hell ... I cant believe this ... I have changed the code a little bit

radGr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
     checkQuestionsAnswer();     
    }
          
         });
and after all buttons are clicked and after a few seconds the button is enabled ???

Answer (score 0):

give radiobuttons id's as well and when you are going to submit this form(for example) mean on button click , get radio button object by id and then check radiobutton.isChecked().